# I can't see my texture, just a black screen instead

Tags: android, kotlin, opengl-es, opengl-es-1.1

I want to display the texture in openGL-ES 1, but the code below just displays a black screen

```
class MyGLRenderer(val context: Context) : GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    private var textureId = 0
    private lateinit var bitmap: Bitmap

    override fun onSurfaceCreated(gl: GL10?, config: EGLConfig?) {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.drawable.bumpy_bricks_public_domain)
        val textures = IntArray(1)
        gl?.glGenTextures(1,textures,0)
        textureId = textures[0]
        gl?.glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f)
        gl?.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,textureId)
        gl?.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
        gl?.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)
        gl?.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL10.GL_NEAREST.toFloat())
        gl?.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL10.GL_NEAREST.toFloat())
        gl?.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE.toFloat())
        gl?.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE.toFloat())
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,bitmap,0)
        bitmap.recycle()
    }

    override fun onSurfaceChanged(gl: GL10?, width: Int, height: Int) {

    }

    override fun onDrawFrame(gl: GL10?) {
        gl?.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
        gl?.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        gl?.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId)
        gl?.glTexCoordPointer(2,GL10.GL_FLOAT,0,textureBuffer)
        gl?.glVertexPointer(3,GL10.GL_FLOAT,0,vertexBuffer)
        gl?.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,4)
        gl?.glDisable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D)
    }

    companion object{
        private val vertexData =
            floatArrayOf(
                -1.0f,-1.0f,0.0f,
                1.0f,-1.0f,0.0f,
                -1.0f,1.0f,0.0f,
                1.0f,1.0f,0.0f
            )
        private val textureData =
            floatArrayOf(
                0.0f,1.0f,
                1.0f,1.0f,
                0.0f,0.0f,
                1.0f,0.0f,
            )
        private val vertexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertexData.size*4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer()
        private val textureBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(textureData.size*4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer()
    }

    init {
        vertexBuffer.put(vertexData).position(0)
        textureBuffer.put(textureData).position(0)
    }

}
```

This is my renderer class
And this is my activity class, where do I initialize my renderer class

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var glSurfaceView:GLSurfaceView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        glSurfaceView = GLSurfaceView(this)
        glSurfaceView.setRenderer(MyGLRenderer(applicationContext))
        setContentView(glSurfaceView)
    }
}
```

I forgot to specify the use of openGL in the manifest, but after I specified, nothing changed.
    `<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00010000" android:required="true"/>`
I can't figure out where the error is in this code.
I would also like to know the best way to display textures in OpenGl-ES 1

Comment: I don't know your exact issue, but I notice a bug. That `init` block that fills your byte buffers would need to be moved inside the `companion object` or else you are needlessly reloading your buffers for every instance of your renderer class. Also, GL10 and EglConfig are never null. You don't need to declare them as nullable. That will allow you to remove all those question marks.